# Wordpress update custom post type meta saved in xml

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a very simple question , i have a  custom post type called player that has various meta keys such as player_dob and player_number .  i want when a player is logged in to be able to update these meta values on the front end . after going through the database i realized that the meta is saved in  xml format

```
<player>
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <player><player_dob>August 15, 1996</player_dob>
    <player_birthplace>Tanga</player_birthplace>
    <player_shirtnumber>35</player_shirtnumber>
</player>
```

So , how do i update forexample player_birthplace  using update_post_meta . Here is my code but it does not work .

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'px_meta_save_player' );  
function px_meta_save_player($current_post_id)
  {
    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement("<player></player>");
  if ( empty($_POST["player_birthplace"]) )$_POST["player_birthplace"] = "";
       $sxe->addChild('player_birthplace', 'Dar-es-salaam' );
       update_post_meta( $current_post_id, 'px_player', $sxe->asXML() );
 }
```

Comment: See this url http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128767/adding-custom-fields-post-meta-before-during-wp-insert-post

Comment: Hi @JakirHossain , Thanks for helping , i have updated my question realizing that the problem was saving the value in xml format , can you please check the code and see what's wrong ?